# Is there any other way to share information on a website apart from typical Blogging, YouTube or Podcast?

Tags: creative-writing, style, technical-writing, blog

I have a website and I want to share content mostly related to security and technology but most of the time I myself don't feel like reading long paragraphs. I am thinking about if there's a unique way of sharing knowledge in a fun and curious way of exploring things. I come up with Infographics but they won't be helpful to me because I also have to share code snippets. Do you think if there's any other way or any tricks which help my readers digest the content? I want to share and explain things but not in a messy way and I don't have a problem writing a lot but as a reader, I myself like to read concise and informative content.

Feel free to share your thoughts down.

Any guidance or tips will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the PowerPoint model -- a slide presentation designed to convey key concepts quickly for an easily bored audience.

In other words, think brief, short statements, bullet lists, occasional sentences and paragraphs, and always a relevant illustration or image. These kind of posts could be created in powerpoint but posted as web pages, separate images, or a scrolling slide show.

The slide show model is definitely geared to the meme-seeking, short-attention-span audience online. It's kind of the opposite of the mostly-text world of journal and magazine articles, blogs, and podcasts.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense and I think this is somewhat related to my audience. I'll start with it yet I will try few other experiments.